# jpa entity graph with query on child attribute

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I am using jpa 2.1 EntityGraphs to modify the different jpa queries and in some cases the EntityGraphs are not working as expected. The simple use case that i am struggling is with

Author as the parent class with unidirectional one to many relationship to Book child class and I want to retrieve author results for a given book name something like findAllAuthorsByBookName.

my Author class looks like this

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.author.detail", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("books")
})
public class Author extends GenericEntity {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="author_id")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();
....
```

Book has no reference back to Author so it looks like this

```
@Entity
public class Book extends GenericEntity {
...
```

Generic Entity class simply has the id and name attributes.

Here is how I am querying for data.

```
EntityGraph graph = em.getEntityGraph("graph.author.detail");       
Author author = (Author) em.createQuery("select a from Author a left join a.books b where b.name = 'book 1'")
                            .setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", graph).getResultList().get(0);
```

This doesnt works. I am expecting Author class to be returned with books attributes eagerly loaded because its specified in the entity graph but in this case the books attribute is lazy loaded and throws LazyInitialziation exception.
If instead I use an attribute on the author for where clause (e.g. `select a from Author a where a.id = 1`) then it works fine and loads the books attribute eagerly.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing something similar with *JPA 2.1/Hibernate*. I believe it may be that since you already have to join to the books collection in your query Hibernate is ignoring the `EntityGraph` hint. The best you might be able to do is a `'left join fetch'` in your query. Not just a `'left join'.`

One thing to note is that it seems to me that the query you actually want is this:

```
"select a from Author a where exists (select 1 from Book b where b.authorId = a.id and b.name = 'book 1')"
```

This will return all Author's that have a book named `'book 1'`. It's possible the `EntityGraph hint` will work properly now, and you won't get duplication of authors in your results.

Also the query above assumes you would at least map the author_id column to a field in both the Author and Book entities, if not just make a bidirectional relationship (in which case it `replace b.authorId = a.authorId with b.author = a.`)